# how to add js and css files in to bootstrap theme in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I am going to add "logo slider" to My laravel app in bootstrap theme. this is My js and css files in blade view

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <meta name="description" content="jQuery Logo Slider Ticker by webdesignandsuch.com">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.bxSlider.js')}}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#slider').bxSlider({
            ticker: true,
            tickerSpeed: 5000,
            tickerHover: true
        });
        });
        </script>

        <link href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

and this is image slide div in same blade file

```
 <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-md-7">
<i><h2>Paper Articals</h2></i>
        <div class="slider-container">

    <ul id="slider">
        <li><a href="#"><p>kkkkkkk</p></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="{{asset('/imgs/2.jpg')}}"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="{{asset('/imgs/3.jpg')}}"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="{{asset('/imgs/4.jpg')}}"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="{{asset('/imgs/5.jpg')}}"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="{{asset('/imgs/6.jpg')}}"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="{{asset('/imgs/7.jpg')}}"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="{{asset('/imgs/8.jpg')}}"></a></li>
    </ul>

</div><!-- /slider -->
      </div>
```

I can show image in the view file but not scrolling. how can fix this prob?

Comment: This is not really a Laravel problem. The only things related to Laravel in your code are `<script src="{{asset('js/jquery.bxSlider.js')}}"></script>` and `<link href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">`. Take a look at the HTML generated, if the file is there and accessible, and got no errors on Web Browser Console (Chrome?), your problem is purely a Javascript problem or bxSlider's.

Comment: I run this code normal html file. then it is running well. but when I add to this to laravel. it is coming this problem. I was add js and css file to public folder correctly.